# how to initialize firebase admin SDK in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am try to initialize firebase admin SDK in my project but it is not working. I intend using it in my next js API for admin backend

```
import {
  initializeApp,
  applicationDefault,
  cert,
} from "firebase-admin/app";
import {
  getFirestore,
  Timestamp,
  FieldValue,
} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import serviceAccount from "../secret.json";

const app = initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
});

export default app.getFirestore();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I want to read and write to my firebase firestore database after initialization. But the initialization is giving me error.

Comment: what is the error? have you read through the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/) about initializing firebase admin?